# Django development

Tags: python, django

This question isn't related to any programming problem or bug rather it's asked to seek knowledge from django developers. I couldnt find proper info as I'm a novice web dev.

I'm a mobile developer and heard quite alot about django. I have looked it up on the internet and official website, from the looks of it, it looks like a framework that is used for storing and retriving data from the database. What are other uses of this framework? 
Can django be used to send and receive data from a mobile device?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "This question isn't related to any programming problem"

Comment: Look, there are lots of articles about Django in web, can you please search it before asking here?

Comment: *"Can django be used to send and receive data from a mobile device?"* - Yeah. Instagram is built using Django. Their mobile app sends and receives data from a server running Django.

Comment: The official Django tutorials provide a very good start. https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Did your problem solve?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not belongs to this site, btw, yes, `Django` is one of the most famous web frameworks of `python`, you can up a server via `wsgi` (or `uwsgi`) module and make a rest-api server via `rest-api-framework`, also create `SOA`.

It depends on your needs, but I think you can use [`DRF`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (Django Rest Framework) to standardize your server.

Answer (score 0):

Django was created by a newspaper that wanted a better way of publishing articles. It is a framework for publishing content in a reliable way, so that different types of articles can have corresponding views.

Since then it has evolved a lot so that it can serve as a back-end for many types of websites. I'd suggest checking the Django tutorial which has a lot of good examples and code samples to run through: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/